# calling function by user input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am newbie in python i want to a input from user and print month name i dont know what i am doing wrong in this code correct me

```
value=raw_input("Enter value to print month ")
    def switch_demo(argument=value):
        switcher = {
            1: "January",
            2: "February",
            3: "March",
            4: "April",
            5: "May",
            6: "June",
            7: "July",
            8: "August",
            9: "September",
            10: "October",
            11: "November",
            12: "December"
        }
        print switcher.get(argument, "Invalid month")

    switch_demo(value)
```

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: if i entered 2 its printing invalid month instead of February code not working

Comment: Change your input to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raw_input accepts value and return it as a string. So when you enter 1 or 2, it is returned as '1' or '2'.

You have to typecast the input value into int explicitly:

```
value=int(raw_input("Enter value to print month "))
```

Or,you can use input() to accept user input as:

```
value = input("Enter value to print month ")
```

Comment: thanks its working negi ji

Comment: Using `input` on Python 2 is like opening the gates of hell for your code.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that your "switcher" dictionary has integer keys, and argument is a string when you call

```
print switcher.get(argument, "Invalid month")
```

One possible solution is to cast argument to int, it should then work.

```
print switcher.get(int(argument), "Invalid month")
```